# navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices() shows audioinput but not videoinput from capture card

Tags: javascript, electron, chromium, mediadevices

I recently installed a M.2 PCIe capture card ([Magewell Eco Capture Dual HDMI M2](https://magewell.com/products/eco-capture-dual-hdmi-m2)) in the expectation that I would be able to access the captures in a chromium renderer (Electron specifically).

I can see the inputs @ /dev/videoX via `v4l2-ctl` and can play the inputs via `ffplay`, but I can not get them to show up in chromium when enumerating media devices. The enumeration does show the two associated audio input types, but not the video inputs.

In the same renderer I am able to enumerate a video input from a USB capture card made by the same manufacturer.

Everything I've been able to find related to the subject is just people sorting out permission issues in the browser, which isn't the case here as I'm running locally in Electron and am capable of sourcing other input devices.

My user has access to the videos in the OS, as evidenced by being able to `ffplay` them.

I've been banging my head against the wall on this all afternoon, any help would be appreciated.

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.